# How to create gstreamer pipeline in python with a probe

Tags: python, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

I am trying to write a code that takes image input, writes some text over it, and then sends it to the sink (app, file, or Gtk display).

The code below works in the terminal and through python:

```py
pipeline = Gst.parse_launch(f"videotestsrc ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080 ! autovideosink")
```

I need a probe here to put some text on the images, so I have converted this in the `gi` format for manipulating it. The code gives no visual or text output. Is there anything wrong with the code:

```py
pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()

source = Gst.ElementFactory.make("videotestsrc", "video-source")
pipeline.add(source)

scale = Gst.ElementFactory.make("videoscale", "scale")
pipeline.add(scale)

caps = Gst.Caps.from_string("video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080")
filter = Gst.ElementFactory.make("capsfilter", "filter")
filter.set_property("caps", caps)
pipeline.add(filter)
scale.link(filter)

sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("autovideosink", "video-sink")
pipeline.add(sink)
filter.link(sink)

loop = GLib.MainLoop()
pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

try:
    loop.run()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't link your `videotestsrc` to your `videoscale` element. In other words, you forgot

```
source.link(scale)
```